# Calling POST method in serverless offline using Postman

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, offline

I'm running serverless offline in node.js. When I try hitting the POST endpoint on Postman the request goes on forever and does not seem to call my handler. I'm not sending anything in the request body. It did not make a difference.

Below are examples of the code I'm running

handlers.js file

```
module.exports.postHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   console.log("Inside POST Method");
}
```

Inside serverless.yml

```
  postHandler:
    handler: src/handlers.postHandler
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: v1/post/handler
```

I have a GET method setup very similarly. That looks to be working fine

Edit:
I tried sending an empty request on an invalid POST route. Postman still keeps sending the request endless. When I try the same with GET I get the error - Serverless-offline: route not found. Not sure why POST requests do not resolve.

Comment: Make sure your app is listening on localhost:port and that you don't have firewall rules blocking it

Comment: @Joe It's listening on the right port. I have a GET method running that is working fine.

Comment: Well then you get 500 because its not implemented, you are making a POST request

Comment: @Joe I have 2 endpoints. One GET method, which is returning the correct response. The 2nd is a POST method that is not returning any response. The call goes on forever.

Comment: You need to respond to the client in your post request handler, you dont. Return 200 and give an empty json response it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond to the client in your post request handler, you dont. Return 200 and give an empty json response it will work

Also make sure you are posting to the API POST Route, and giving it data it needs. i.e)

example:

```
// dont forget content type and content length headers
POST(host, path, { body: { ...data } })
```

example get:

```
GET(host, path, "?query=params")
```

Your current handler

module.exports.postHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
console.log("Inside POST Method");
}

do,

```
module.exports.postHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   context.status = 200;
   context.message = "Youre welcome"
}
```

Comment: It still did not work

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact same issue.

In my case too the GET requests worked but the POST requests didn't return any response and the call would go on forever.

I did 3 things to solve this.

1. I updated `serverless-offline` dependency to the latest version.

> npm i -D serverless-offline@latest

2. In `serverless.yml` file, I updated the runtime environment of NodeJs to the one currently installed on my system.

```
provider:
  runtime: nodejs16.x
```

3. In `serverless.yml` file, I updated the custom settings as per the latest version of the dependency.

```
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 9000
```